# In Android when trying to multithread why am I getting a handler warning?

Tags: android, static, warnings, handler

So I'm threading an activity because I want to put in a loading screen

While it puts on a loading screen the app first checks to see if the user's logged in and if they're not an error screen loads.

At the end of the thread I just have

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

For handler I have

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pd.dismiss();
        if (badkey==1)
        {
            reloginDlog().show();
        }
    }
    };
```

pd is a progress dialog  and badkey is a public int.

I'm getting a warning in the private Handler line that says "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (MyActivity.1)"

So does anyone know why this is bad and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try rather sth like: (thread is associated with handler should have initialised message loop - `Looper.prepare()` and `.loop()`):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Looper.prepare();

            handler = new Handler() {

                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    // process incoming messages here
                    //...

                    //destroy message cue when no longer needed 
                    if(noMoreMessagesToHandle) {

                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }
                }
            };

            Looper.loop();

        }

    }).start();
```

Comment: I got back "Cannot instantiate the type Handler.Callback"

Comment: How do you create the thread in which you instantiate the Handler?

Comment: Oh wait it's iniitialized by private Handler handler= new Handler(new Handler.Callback(). I think.

Comment: what is `this`? (what interfaces/classes over Runnable?)

Comment: extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, Runnable

Comment: I also have another one that also extends ListActivity but only implements Runnable.

Comment: It's in onCreate if that's what you mean.

Comment: Activity should rather not be Runnable. Define Runnable as separate object (local or member).

Comment: noMoreMessagesToHandle is giving me an error, also do I put the stuff I now have in run() before or after Looper.prepare?

Comment: Ok well it's a loading screen so I think it'll only use the thread and it'll send a message when it's done loading or has encountered a login error (and if there is a login error the activity is terminated), so should I just have it quit after one message?

Comment: by noMoreMessagesToHandle i meant a custom boolean flag - when you no longer want to use the handler quit message loop.

Comment: I meant to say in the other one that I think I'll only use it once, but there's more than one activity with a thread.